# Why can't we look at the future with telescopes?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, causality

I understand that space-time in non-linear. How come, though, all the light captured by telescopes allows us to see only the past in all directions but not the future? Does that mean that there are no galaxies formed before the Milky Way? Does that mean any life form in the Universe can only see the past, providing that it is equipped to do so?
It doesn't really seem that I can even formulate the question correctly but, if anyone understands what I trying to ask, I'll appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Ask Doc Brown and be nice to Einstein.

Comment: Light travels from past to future, not future to past.

Comment: There is a cosmological model, described at https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0111191 , which allows for the possibility that beings in one of two "causally-separated" regions (basically, two separate regions that would each be a "local universe" in an inflationary "multiverse", with the inhabitants in one of those regions remaining forever out of any contact with those in the other) might see the future, but not the past, through their telescopes, whereas those in the other might (like ourselves) see the past  but not the future.  It was accepted by Borde, Guth, & Vilenkin in a major theorem.

Comment: In my opinion, this question should not have been closed, and it would be parasitic of me to "improve" it:  Guth & Vilenkin were two of the founders of inflationary cosmology, and their acceptance of the model (by Aguirre & Gratton) that I mentioned can be seen in the last footnote to the last (2003's) revision of the extremely influential BGV Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

To enlarge a bit on Bob's answer (Hi Bob and welcome to the physics SE):

It takes time for light to travel from its source to our telescopes and then into our eyes. This means that *whenever we are "looking" at anything in our world by using light, we are seeing it as it appeared in the past*, when those photons were originally emitted.

For objects close to us, that travel time delay is of order ~billionths of a second, which for practical purposes we can consider negligible. For distant galaxies, that time delay is of order ~billions of years, which means we see those galaxies through our telescopes as they appeared billions of years ago.

To see into the future would require the photons to travel not forwards but *backwards* in time, which is something they do not do.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification - makes total sense. Your answer made me think about the following though: is it possible to have something before photons exist although we wouldn't be able to see it, as perhaps before the Big Bang? If there is something before photons, would it be correct to assume that our species isn't equipped to see whatever was there before photons? If all that may be true, could we indeed see the future if we were equipped or had the right instruments to do so? Should that instrument exist one day, could we then see the future?

Comment: Photons are all there is to "see" with; they are the means by which causality is propagated in our universe. If there were anything else we would have found it by now. Remember that "seeing the future" means detecting things which haven't happened yet- this is a hard job!

Comment: This answer is completely valid for the only one of the paired universes, that I mentioned in my earlier comments, which may ever be susceptible to astronomical observation by us.

Answer (score 2):

I am a newbie also but I'd like to take a shot at answering your question about only seeing light from the past. Since the light (photon) entering a telescope had to originate somewhere (past or future) we can only capture it in a telescope AFTER its been created. If we could capture it before it was created we might be able to "see" the future but there would be nothing to see.

Comment: There is a possibility that the light has, especially in the context of a multiverse, always existed, although some or all of it may, at times, have existed only in some form of potential, such as a singularity or a sequence of related (similar or identical) singularities.  ("Created" can be a little bit of a buzz word, in physics.)